# Mysql Replication for selected tables from a database?

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I think that Mysql replication could be the solution that I am searching for. I need to sync some of the tables in a database.

The trouble is that I only need to sync SOME tables and not all of them. Anyone did this before ? If you did ... how did you do it ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under `--replicate-do-table=name`

See - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table